# Problems with reading in a text file

Tags: r, csv, file-io, text-processing

I'm trying to read a text file into R using the below code:

```
d = read.table("test_data.txt")
```

It returned the following error message:

```
"Error in scan(file, what, nmax, sep, dec, quote, skip, nlines, na.strings,  : 
  line 2 did not have 119 elements"
```

I tried this:

```
read.table("man_cohort9_check.txt", header=T, sep="\t")
```

but it gave this error:

```
"Error in scan(file, what, nmax, sep, dec, quote, skip, nlines, na.strings,  : 
  line 43 did not have 116 elements"
```

I don't understand what's going wrong??

Answer (score 5):

It's because your file has rows with different number of column. To start investigate you can run:

```
d = read.table("test_data.txt", fill=TRUE, header=TRUE, sep="\t")
```

Comment: @agstudy oh yeah.. :-) `T<-1; > T [1] 1` while `> TRUE<-1
Error in TRUE <- 1 : invalid (do_set) left-hand side to assignment` That's much safer!

Comment: yup much safer! in a second approach myb OP should see how to read delimited files , `read.fwf`!

Answer (score 0):

The usual cause of this are unmatched quotes and or lurking octothorpes ("#"). I would investigate these by seeing which of these produces the most regular table:

```
table( countfields("test_data.txt", quote="", comment.char="") )
table( countfields("test_data.txt", quote="") )
table( countfields("test_data.txt", comment.char="") )
```